# Sass in stack snippets

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

Most of you have probably seen stack snippets, like the one below.

```js
function clickMe() {
  alert("Button clicked!");
}
```

```css
button {
  background-color: rgb(29 78 216);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(30 64 175);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -3px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1), 0 4px 6px -4px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1);
}

button:active {
  background-color: rgb(30 58 138);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clickMe()">Click me!</button>
```

The problem is that I have to use `button`, `button:hover`, *and* `button:active`. It would be much easier to use [Sass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29).

```css
button {
  background-color: rgb(29 78 216);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.2s;

  &:hover {
    background-color: rgb(30 64 175);
      box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -3px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1), 0 4px 6px -4px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1);
  }

  &:active {
    background-color: rgb(30 58 138);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find an option in the stack snippet generator to include Sass. So is there built-in support for Sass in stack snippets? If so, where can I find it? But if not, can Stack Overflow add Sass support?

Comment: In your case, I wouldn't call it *much* easier. It barely saves you any typing (10 characters less, if we disregard the whitespace). And in general, I feel like if you *need* SASS for a snippet, it's not really *minimal* example. Well, unless you are asking some question specifically for SASS, I suppose.

Comment: Is it *"stack snippets"* or *"[Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/stack-snippets/info)"* (not a rhetorical question)?

Comment: *The Sass compiler is written in C++, so it would be more or less impossible to run it inside a browser. Instead you could use Less, that runs pretty well inside a browser.*  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61664658) So, for Sass, probably not. For Less, yes, I'm sure it's *doable*, but like VLAZ says, better to trim to a MCVE without introducing another technology into the mix

Comment: I disagree fundamentally. SASS is a compiler that outputs CSS. It does not interact directly with the browser, or with HTML. If your question is about SASS, you should not use stack snippets, you should include SASS without any associated HTML or JavaScript; if your question is about HTML, CSS and JavaScript, your MCVE by definition should not include SASS code. SASS is a layer of complexity that should be stripped away if you're producing a MCVE. If your question includes both SASS and HTML, then it certainly is not an MCVE.

Comment: I left a [significantly longer answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419029/229044) on the dupe.